# Android viewmodel pass parameter to view model from view

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines, android-viewmodel

I have a Fragment code -

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
   super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

   val safeArgs: PetDetailsViewArgs by navArgs()
   val petId = safeArgs.petId

   viewModel.getPetDetailsForId(petId).observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
     // ...
   })
}
```

I have a ViewModel code -

```
private val viewState = PetDetailsViewState()

fun getPetDetailsForId(id: String?): LiveData<PetDetailsViewState> {
   return if (id.isNullOrEmpty()) {
         liveData {
             emit(
                 viewState.copy(
                     loading = false,
                     error = ErrorType.PET_ID_NULL_OR_EMPTY
                 )
             )
         }
        } else {
            petDetailsLiveData
        }
    }

    var petDetailsLiveData = petService.performPetAction(PetAction.GetPetDetails("2")).map {
            when (it) {
                // ...
            }
        }.asLiveData(Dispatchers.Default + viewModelScope.coroutineContext)
```

As you see in my ViewModel, I am at the moment hardcoding the id in `PetAction.GetPetDetails("2")` which is not correct.

How do I pass the id from my view to viewModel?

Comment: Maybe I missunderstand your question, but what I see is that you already pass your `petId` to your ViewModel function `getPetDetailsForId(id: String?)`. So you could just pass `id` to `PetAction.GetPetDetails(id)`. Or which _id from your view_ are you talking then?

Comment: @ChristianB The variable petDetailsLiveData is outside the function getPetDetailsForId. So I cannot pass the id.

Comment: From your example code `petDetailsLiveData` is declared inside `fun getPetDetailsForId()`

Comment: @ChristianB Ok the variable is outside the function

Comment: I see, please update your code sample in your question then, so others will see this too.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options, if the `petId` (from the Fragment) does not change, you could create / inject your ViewModel and pass the `petId` via Constructor.

Can your `petId` be `null`? If not you can then directly initialize your LiveData and observe it from your Fragment.

```kotlin
class PetViewModel(petId: String): ViewModel() {
  val petDetailsLiveData = petService.performPetAction(PetAction.GetPetDetails(petId)).map {
            // ...
        }.asLiveData(Dispatchers.Default + viewModelScope.coroutineContext)
}
```

Second option, as you showed in your question, if `petId` can change, create the LiveData within the function `getPetDetailsForId(id: String?)`.

```kotlin
fun getPetDetailsForId(id: String?): LiveData<PetDetailsViewState> {
   return if (id.isNullOrEmpty()) {
         liveData {
             emit(
                 viewState.copy(
                     loading = false,
                     error = ErrorType.PET_ID_NULL_OR_EMPTY
                 )
             )
         }
        } else {
            petService.performPetAction(PetAction.GetPetDetails("2")).map {
              // ...
            }.asLiveData(Dispatchers.Default + viewModelScope.coroutineContext)
    }
```

**After discussion**

You can consider some caching of your `petId` and the `PetDetailsViewState` to avoid duplicate api calls. Take this a a very simple example of getting the idea. There is much to improve here.

```kotlin
class PetViewModel : ViewModel() {

 private val cachedPetDetailsViewState: PetDetailsViewState? = null
 private val cachedPetId: String = "" 

 fun getPetDetailsForId(id: String?): LiveData<PetDetailsViewState> {
   if (id == cachedPetId && cachedPetDetailsViewState != null) return MutableLiveData(cachedPetDetailsViewState)

   cachedPetId == id

   if (id.isNullOrEmpty() { ... }
   else { 
     val petIdViewState = // make the API call
 
     cachedPetDetailsViewState = petIdViewState
     
     return MutableLiveData(petIdViewState)
   }   
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. With the first option, I have the id changing so could not use that. With second option it works, but the problem is when you rotate the screen, the view is created new and the viewModel is called and the petService is called again i.e on every screen rotation, a new API call is made. That was the reason I went with the variable approach since it gets updated with the state no matter the screen orientation changes and does not result in calling the petService again and again.

Comment: I see, I recommend adding this information to your question, as it gives important details on your problem. You could then think of caching/storing the `petId` you made last. If it is the same, you do not make another request.

Comment: Sure that approach would work as well but I would be missing out the cleaner way of doing i.e the viewModel surviving the orientation change and handling the data for me.

Comment: I updated my answer, showing some very simple caching strategy. I think you could also make something similar using MediatorLiveData.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I found one more way of doing it which I have posted as an answer. Could you please share your thoughts on it and let me know if it is fine to do the way I posted. That would be really helpful

Comment: Unfortunately I never used `SavedStateHandle`. I think it's best you try it out and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to do with `savedStateHandle` -

Here is my Fragment -

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
   super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

   viewModel.petDetailsViewData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {

   })
}
```

ViewModel -

```
class PetDetailsViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(
    private val petService: PetService,
    @Assisted private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
) :
    ViewModel() {

    private val viewState = PetDetailsViewState()
    var petDetailsViewData =
        petService.performPetAction(PetAction.GetPetDetails(savedStateHandle.get<String>("petId")!!))
            .map {
                when (it) {
                    // ... 
                }
            }.asLiveData(Dispatchers.Default + viewModelScope.coroutineContext)
}
```

I basically use safeArgs key inside viewModel and access it via savedStateHandle. This way I don't need to bother my view with accessing ids and also on configuration change, I only call my service once.